# Travis and OpenCV 3 - How To install?

Tags: python, opencv, travis-ci

I am trying to use Travis for an open-source project that use OpenCV with Python 3.

```
before_install:
- virtualenv venv
- sudo apt-get update

install:
- pip install --upgrade pip
- pip install -r requirements.txt

# Installing OpenCV
- sudo apt-get install python-dev python-numpy
- git clone https://github.com/Itseez/opencv.git
- cd opencv
- mkdir build
- cd build
- cmake ..
- make -j4
- sudo make -j4 install
- mvn install:install-file -Dfile=/usr/local/share/OpenCV/java/opencv-300.jar -DgroupId=opencv -DartifactId=opencv -Dversion=3.0.0 -Dpackaging=jar
- cd ../..
```

Two problems:

1. This install script fails on compiling.
2. It take ages to execute, and I would like a much simpler (and faster) solution. Can't I just apt-get install or pip install something that would do the job just as good ?

Comment: I got script from here: https://gist.github.com/cgddrd/9d397fda0d72fe617c0e and it works, but as you said it takes lot of time to rebuild opencv each time.

Comment: You should be able to use: `pip install opencv-python` See [https://pypi.python.org/pypi/opencv-python](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/opencv-python).

Comment: on before_install put this
"pip2 uninstall numpy"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Catree, `pip install opencv-python` was the solution.